# How to see assembly code in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, assembly, xcode6

How to see assembly code generated by compiler while running application using iOS device in xcode 6.What are the settings i should enable in xcode to see assembly code?

Answer (score 9):

In Xcode Options,

Select the option

> Debug->Debug WorkFlow-> Always Show Disassembly

Put break point in the code where you want to see assembly code. Then you can view assembly code when code reached to that breakpoint.